# How can I extract a substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, find, substring, indexof

I need to extract a sub string, particularly **"Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)** from this string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Find String</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = '<div class="view view-commerce-line-item-table view-id-commerce_line_item_table view-display-id-default view-dom-id-57765ff55f834d6a7ec1b8f510768a90">
<div class="view-content">
<table class="views-table cols-4"><thead><tr><th class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
            Title          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
            Unit price          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-quantity">
            Quantity          </th>
<th class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
            Total          </th>
</tr></thead><tbody><tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">
             "Sweet Heart" Package    (SPA02)          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price">
            135.00  CAD          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-quantity">
            1          </td>
<td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right">
            135.00  CAD          </td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
</div>';
    var n = str.indexOf('class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried this to find the beginning of the string:
`str.indexOf('class="odd views-row-first views-row-last"><td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title">');`
but it doesn't return a valid integer position, it in fact doesn't return anything... and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and how i'd best go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: check you developer console. It looks like you have a syntax error. Specifically, a string across multiple lines.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I definitely do, are you saying a string across multiple lines is invalid in javascript ? :o

Comment: Yes, for some reason, that was the design decision.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara do I have any aalternatives, then?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara looks like I need to put a \ at the end of each line.... ghow can I do this programatically then? :o

Comment: If it comes from a server-side scripting language like PHP, encode it using a JSON encoder. If not, [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883553/what-are-modern-uses-of-script-type-text-html-and-is-this-example-cosidered-go).

Comment: from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript `var myString = (function () {/*
   <div id="someId">
     some content<br />
     <a href="#someRef">someRefTxt</a>
    </div>        
*/}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];` seems to work for me... more work required to confirm tho. You can move this from comments to answer an i'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare a JavaScript string across multiple lines. You will get a syntax error.

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Alternative options include:

### Escape the newline:

```
var str = '<div>\
    test\
</div>';
```

### Concatenate:

```
var str = '<div>' + 
'    test' + 
'</div>';
```

### Store it in a DOM element:

```
<script id="my_str" type="text/html">
<div>
    test
</div>
</script>
```

And retrieve like so:

```
doucment.getElementById('my_str').innerHTML;
```

### Using PHP:

```
var str = <?php echo json_encode( $your_html_string ); ?>;
```