# unknown "<#" construct in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie in js.. but I found a construct I've never seen and although googled a little, haven't fount any info:

here a piece of code I found with slider revolution:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-attachment-details-two-column">
    <div class="attachment-media-view {{ data.orientation }}">
        <div class="thumbnail thumbnail-{{ data.type }}">
            <# if ( data.uploading ) { #>
                <div class="media-progress-bar"><div></div></div>
            <# } else if ( 'image' === data.type && data.sizes && data.sizes.large ) { #>
                <img class="details-image" src="{{ data.sizes.large.url }}" draggable="false" />
            <# } else if ( 'image' === data.type && data.sizes && data.sizes.full ) { #>
                <img class="details-image" src="{{ data.sizes.full.url }}" draggable="false" />
            <# } else if ( -1 === jQuery.inArray( data.type, [ 'audio', 'video' ] ) ) { #>
                <img class="details-image" src="{{ data.icon }}" class="icon" draggable="false" />
            <# } #>
....
</script>
```

what is it used for?
what's the rules?
Thanks

Comment: It's some kind of template and <# #> is to add logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't JavaScript, see the `type="text/html"`? This is an HTML template.

See [What are modern uses of script type="text/html" and is this example considered good use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13883553/871050) (among other similar questions).

Comment: Opps.. I saw '<script' and I thought was Javascript.. did not know was also other type of script..
Thanks a lot!